# Extracting enum flags to list with generic method?

Tags: c#, list, generics, enums, .net-core-2.1

## Ideology

I am attempting to extract enum flags from a value and convert them into a `List` or `HashSet` with 0 (None) being excluded.

The Framework I am targeting is `.Net Core 2.1`. I've been able to do this with a specific enums, however, I want to extend this method to accept any sort of enum that is int-based using a generic method to convert to a `List` or `HashSet` to reduce boilerplate code.

### Code

```cs
public enum Numbers
{
    None = 0,
    One  = 1,
    Two  = 2,
    Four = 4
}

public enum Teams
{
    None       = 0,
    Stars      = 1,
    Blackhawks = 2,
    Penguins   = 4,
    Devils     = 8
}

public static List<Numbers> EnumToList(Numbers n)
{
    List<Numbers> numberList = new List<Numbers>();

    // Extract values until we hit None / 0.
    while (n != 0)     // Originally: (n != Numbers.None)
    {
        foreach (Numbers i in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Numbers)))
        {
            if (n == 0)
                break;  // Prevent excess looping.

            if ((n & i) == i && i != Numbers.None)
            {   // Found a valid item.
                numberList.Add(i);  
                n &= ~i;    // Remove the value.
            }
        }
    }

    return numberList;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Numbers nums = Numbers.One | Numbers.Four;

    List<Numbers> items = EnumToList(nums);
    if (items.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (Numbers n in items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Extracted Value: {Enum.GetName(typeof(Numbers), n)}");
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

### Result

```
Extracted Value: One
Extracted Value: Four
Press enter to exit.
```

## Desired Ability and Result

Pass flags of the type `Teams` through the same function to get a list.

```
Teams t = Teams.Stars | Teams.Blackhawks | Teams.Devils;
List<Teams> teams = EnumToList(t);
```

Result:

```
Extracted Value: Stars
Extracted Value: Blackhawks
Extracted Value: Devils
Press enter to exit.
```

## Conclusion

I am aware that I will have to use a generic method such as:

```
public static List<TEnum> EnumToList<TEnum>(TEnum value) { }
```

But I am entirely lost where to go from here so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So what’s wrong with the code at the moment? What exactly is your question?

Comment: Instead of `EnumToList()` working on a specific `enum`, I would like it to be a generic method that can take any enum with combined flags and convert it to a `List` of that enum's type with members of the `List` each being an extracted flag.

Comment: So when you changed it into a generic method as you showed and made it use the given type, what happened?

Comment: `value` in the while loop cannot be converted to an int. Casting with (int)value or (enum)Value works to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this

**Given**

```
[Flags]
public enum TestEnum
{
    None = 0,
    AA = 1,
    BB = 2,
    CC = 4,
    DD = 8,
}
```

**Method**

```
public static IEnumerable<T> EnumerateMask<T>(Enum mask)
    => Enum.GetValues(typeof (T))
           .Cast<Enum>()
           .Where(mask.HasFlag)
           .Cast<T>()
           .Skip(1);
```

**Usage**

```
var mask = TestEnum.AA | TestEnum.None | TestEnum.DD;

foreach (var value in EnumerateMask<TestEnum>(mask))
    Console.WriteLine(value);
```

**Output**

```
AA
DD
```

***Disclaimer*** : Obviously due-diligence and fault tolerance is required

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/05iCcb)

Comment: This works perfectly for what I asked for! I'll add some additional checks and expand on this a smudge- but beyond I'm not sure it could get much cleaner than this for an answer. Thank you.